# object expected error from Seadragon and IE

Tags: javascript, browser, deepzoom, seadragon

I'm playing around with seadragon trying to make a deepzoom image. [I have uploaded it here](http://www.qaz.dk/dzviewer.aspx).

In Firefox and Chrome it works fine, but IE produces a JavaScript error like

> an obect was expectet. Linie 95

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of prototypejs(1.4 from 2005), which causes an error before the one in line 95(Array.shift tries to assign an invalid value to the length of an array, prototype.js line 464). Try using a newer version of prototypejs.

Comment: Thats right, I have now upgraded lightbox, and everything works perfect. Can i ask how did you spot the error the message from IE isnt very helpfull. Thank you

Comment: I got a good description of the error(IE6, script-debugger told me something about a expected non-negative, finite value for array.length )